# Google calendar remider before start event

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-client

Hi have added [Watch](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch) on google calendar, I want to get reminder before event start on [Channel](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/channels) , there is any method to get notification on channel before event start, is it possible , I found [concepts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders). But not not very much clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I found these tutorials that are easy to understand and have very good explanations which you can add to your references:

- [Set a notification for a user chosen time](http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/)
- [EventKit Tutorial: Making a Calendar Reminder](https://www.raywenderlich.com/64513/cookbook-making-calendar-reminder)

I hope the tutorials made the concepts clearer. Happy coding! :)